# How to directly edit a row in a UITableView, without entering in Editing Mode

Tags: objective-c, ios

In a `UITableView`, I would like to be able to edit the `cell.textLabel.text` property of the row, when such row is touched.

In other terms, I would like to be able to edit the row directly touching it, instead of entering into edit mode.

How can I implement this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CMTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CMTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    int tagsCount = [[currentComic Tags] count];

    [[cell textField] setTag:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textField] setText:[tagsDisplayName objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

And this is the subclass CMTableViewCell:

```
...

-(void)viewDidLoad
{    
    textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [textField setFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,50,400)];
    [self addSubview:textField];
}
```

Comment: implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `UITextField` without borders as subview. Before adding it to subview - set Tag nubmer to `UITextField` from `indexPath.row` at `tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. When user entered data - save it with `UITextFieldDelegate` methods when "Return" button was pressed. Unfortunately I can't give you code, because right now I'm on Windows. Home this will help

**UPDATE**: Tag number needed to change data in your DataSource. When you pressed "Return" button in your UITextField, you can save changed by getting UITableViewCell by this tag number from UITextField.

Comment: But do you mean a UITextField for each row, or a UITextField as popup field displaying over the table while editing ? (I think you meant the second one).

Comment: @Patrick, yes, for each. I suggest you to create custom row. It will be much easier

Answer (score 0):

It's simple:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                             didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"...";
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
                             didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
    [textField setTag:[indexPath row]];
    [tagsTableView addSubview:textField];
    FreeAndNil(textField);
}
```

Comment: Ya but I would like to type the content of the new row I mean, to pop up the keyboard and let the user to change the content of the row

Comment: okay, sry i missunderstood your question, so the best solution is @Timur answer.

Comment: Should I add the UITextField to the UITableView ?

Comment: @Patrick not to the UITableView. Add it to each UITableViewRow

Comment: I've added the code to my question. I've added the UITextField but I can't still see the text displayed in the cell.

Comment: Your text will be displayed in this UITextField, not in the UILabel. Create custom Cell in Interface Builder, it will be easier for you. Find documentation how to create and use custom Cells.

Comment: `[indexPath row]` can also be `indexPath.row` . . . `[[Class alloc] init]` can be shortened to `[Class new]` . . . What is `FreeAndNil()`?